# rsync not working for remote copy?

Tags: bash, rsync

I do the following command

```
 rsync -a toCopy/Read_Files/ toCopy/Test
```

and it works. However when I try through remote access :

```
 rsync -a toCopy/Read_Files/ root@192.168.155.148:/NightTest/
```

I got the following message

```
sh: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Even though I followed instruction from this site

http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/

section *Copy a Directory from Local Server to a Remote Server*

**See my answer to know what to do if you can't use rsync

Comment: it depends on your remote side. from the error msg, you can see it's a connection failure, which means rsync recognizes your parameters

Comment: I do lots of scp before, after and they all work. how would it be possible?

Comment: want to try it, I read about it, but not sure, I add --rsync-path="path to rsync command"
but then what is the path supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using scp command instead, turned out one of the server didn't have rsync.

See this solution for scp command

https://serverfault.com/questions/264595/can-scp-copy-directories

For rsync, this may be useful if you have similar errors that I have but you have rsync on BOTH machine

[rsync'ing files between two remote servers, get errors stating rsync command not found on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732039/rsyncing-files-between-two-remote-servers-get-errors-stating-rsync-command-not)

The error was indeed pointing out to the fact that the remote machine did not have it :

```
sh: rsync: command not found
```

This error was only occurring when doing it remotely, indicating that the remote machine was not able to find this command.