# Why my perl script requires to export packages path into @INC to run remotely via ssh

Tags: perl, ssh, export

The server perl script - with its required packages - works locally by the user "my_user".

But if I run the script remotely (ssh), I need to *`export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/my_modules`* before calling the perl script to get it working.

Why this and how can I turn around this in order to avoid exporting PERLIB each time I need to call a remote perl script ?

**WORKING** :

```
ssh my_user@remote_server "export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/my_modules; /cgi-bin/my_perl_script.pl --option1 foo --option2 '*';"
```

**NOT WORKING** :

```
ssh my_user@remote_server "/cgi-bin/my_perl_script.pl --option1 foo --option2 '*';"
```

returns :
Can't locate my_package1.pm in @INC

That might be rather an ssh question than a strict perl point : why the remote user running the perl script does not inherit from its ENV local datas.

Thx

Comment: Non-interactive shells don't use the same configuration as interactive ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-manu/216204#216204

Comment: On the remote system, which `perl` is being invoked by the script? and what do you see from `<path to that perl>/perl -V`, compared to the output of your local perl?  You shouldn't need *any* environment variables to run a perl script, locally or remotely, if it has been set up properly.

Comment: @Ether: thx for the comment : if I run /usr/bin/perl -V locally (on the remote machine), I have my lib path /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/my_modules included in @INC, but not if I run ssh my_user@remote_server "/usr/bin/perl -V" despite this is the same single perl bin.

Comment: @mu: yep I guess this is the point I worked around somehow intituively (interactive shell when login/non interactive shell when ssh). I have never figured this out at all (I'm a big noob, still learning all by doing). Thank you.

Comment: @hornet: what do you mean "the same single perl bin" -- aren't you using a totally separate system to run the remote request? Unless they share a filesystem e.g. NFS, these are totally separate perl installations, and the required packages may not be installed there.

Comment: @Ether: I run a perl script hosted on a server. This server includes perl (here on this server, I meant a single perl version). I run this script from another machine via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @mu_is_too_short (no friction is good as well), and linking to a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-manu), there are different types of shells : "the SSH command execution shell is a non-interactive shell, whereas your normal shell is either a login shell or an interactive shell".

So the solution is what I did on purpose (eg adding *"export PERL5LIB"* before running the script), or better, source the whole environement from the remote user to run the remote shell with the expected behavior.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "source the whole environment"?