# Pass variables to remote script through SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am running scripts on a remote server from a local server via SSH. The script gets copied over using SCP in a first place, then called while being passed some arguments as follows:

```
scp /path/to/script server.example.org:/another/path/

ssh server.example.org \
MYVAR1=1 \
MYVAR2=2 \
/another/path/script
```

This works fine and on the remote server, the variables `MYVAR1` and `MYVAR2` are available with their corresponding value.

The issue is that these scripts are in constant development which requires the SSH command to be changed every-time a variable is renamed, added, or removed.

I'm looking for a way of passing all the local environment variables to the remote script (since `MYVAR1` and `MYVAR2` are actually local environment variables) which would address the SSH command maintenance issue.

Since `MYVAR1=1 \` and `MYVAR1=1 \` are lines which follow the `env` command output I tried replacing them with the actual command as follows:

```
ssh server.example.org \
`env`
/another/path/script
```

This seems to work for "simple" `env` output lines (e.g. `SHELL=/bin/bash` or `LOGNAME=sysadmin`), however I get errors for more "complex" output lines (e.g. `LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;[...]` which gives errors such as `-bash: 34:ln=01: command not found` ). I can get rid of these errors by unsetting the variables corresponding to those complex output lines before running the SSH command (e.g. `unset LS_COLORS`, then `ssh [...]`) however I don't find this very solution very reliable.

**Q: Does anybody know how to pass all the local environment variables to a remote script via SSH?**

PS: the local environment variables are not environment variables available on the remote machine [so I cannot use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-manu).

**Update with solution**

I ended using `sed` to format the `env` command output from `VAR=VALUE` to `VAR="VALUE"` (and concatenating all lines in to 1) which prevents bash from interpreting some of the output as commands and fixes my problem.

```
ssh server.example.org \
`env | sed 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1="\2"/' | tr '\n' ' '` \
"/another/path/script"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I happened to read the `sshd_config` man page unrelated to this and found the option `AcceptEnv`:

> **AcceptEnv**
>               Specifies what environment variables sent by the client
>   will be
>               copied into the session's environ(7).  See SendEnv in
>               ssh_config(5) for how to configure the client.  Note that
>   envi-
>               ronment passing is only supported for protocol 2. 
>   Variables are
>               specified by name, which may contain the wildcard
>   characters `*'
>               and`?'.  Multiple environment variables may be separated
>   by
>               whitespace or spread across multiple AcceptEnv directives.
>   Be
>               warned that some environment variables could be used to
>   bypass
>               restricted user environments.  For this reason, care
>   should be
>               taken in the use of this directive.  The default is not to
>   accept
>               any environment variables.

Maybe you could use this with `AcceptEnv: *`? I haven't got a box with sshd handy, but try it out!

Comment: I'd recommend using a common prefix, rather than setting it to `*` (which could be somewhat risky)

Comment: @Hasturkun: Indeed, that would generally be better. However, as I understood the question, it seemed user359650 wanted it to be a non-invasive, full copy. Maybe it could be restricted to only do this for a certain user?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not expecting `sshd` to offer such facility. Unfortunately modifying `sshd` isn't an option as it would apply to all users and add another tool to the maintenance list.

Comment: That is an understandable point. Unfortunatly the `Match` directive for `sshd_config` does not allow `AcceptEnv`, otherwise at least the "all users" concern would have been addressed.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `set` instead of `env`.

From the bash manual:

> Without options, the name and value of each shell variable are displayed in a format that can be reused as input for setting or resetting the currently-set variables.

This will take care of all your semi-colon and backslash issues.

```
scp /path/to/script server.example.org:/another/path/
set > environment
scp environment server.example.org:/another/path/
ssh server.example.org "source environment; /another/path/script"
```

If there are any variables you don't want to send over you can filter them out with something like:

```
set | grep -v "DONT_NEED" > environment
```

You could also update the `~/.bash_profile` on the remote system to run the environment script as you log in so you wouldn't have to run the environment script explicit:

```
ssh server.example.org "/another/path/script"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `;` mark the end of your command. You must escape them:

Try whit this command:

```
env | sed 's/;/\\;/g'
```

**Update**:
I tested the command whit a remote host and it worked for me using this command:

```
var1='something;using semicolons;'
ssh hostname "`env | sed 's/;/\\\\;/g' | sed 's/.*/set &\;/g'` echo \"$var1\""
```

I double escape `;` whit `\\\\;` and then I use an other sed substitution to output variables in the form of `set name=value;`. Doing this ensure every variables get setted correclty on the remote host before executing the command.

Answer (score 1):

How about uploading the environment at the same time?

```
scp /path/to/script server.example.org:/another/path/
env > environment
scp environment server.example.org:/another/path
ssh server.example.org "source environment; /another/path/script"
```

Comment: The idea is there however `source environment` still breaks because of the "complex" env output lines which are interpreted as commands.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;
use Getopt::Long;

my $usage = "Usage:\n  $0 --env=FOO --env=BAR ... [user\@]host command args\n\n";

my @envs;
GetOptions("env=s" => \@envs)
    or die $usage;

my $host = shift @ARGV;
die $usage unless defined $host and @ARGV;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect to remote host: " . $ssh->error;

my @cmds;
for my $env (@envs) {
    next unless defined $ENV{$env};
    push @cmds, "export " . $ssh->shell_quote($env) .'='.$ssh->shell_quote($ENV{$env})
}

my $cmd = join('&&', @cmds, '('. join(' ', @ARGV) .')');
warn "remote command: $cmd\n";
$ssh->system($cmd);
```

And it will not break in case your environment variables contain funny things as quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for me.
Suppose you have script which takes two params or have two variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "local"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
/usr/bin/ssh root@192.168.1.2 "/path/test.sh \"$1\" \"$2\";"
```

And script test.sh on 192.168.1.2:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "remote"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

Output will be:

```
local
This is first params
And this is second
remote
This is first params
And this is second
```