# How to SSH and run a bash script with variables?

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I have a script file (`sub.sh`) with the variable inside, for example:

```
cp -r "$dir1" "$dir2"
chmod 600 "$dir2"
# and many other commands...
```

I have another script (`main.sh`) that prepare the variables, export them to the environment, and run the script file above on another server via SSH. I tried the following command but it doesn't work because the variables are not pre-processed before passing to the server:

```
cat ./sub.sh | ssh $user@$ip
```

I know that I can use Heredoc like this:

```
ssh $user@ip << EOF
  cp -r "$dir1" "$dir2"
  chmod 600 "$dir2"
  # and many other commands...
EOF
```

but the script is long and I want to split the file to make the code cleaner.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Do any of the solutions in ["Pass variables to remote script through SSH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746168/pass-variables-to-remote-script-through-ssh) solve your problem? It looks like a variant of David Newcomb's answer would work (provided the local and remote shells are both bash): `{ set; cat ./sub.sh; } | ssh $user@$ip`

Comment: You wrote: `main.sh` prepares and export the variables. Is this on the local or remote server?

Comment: @WalterA It's on my local. I want to run the script in multiple servers. The number of servers may change and I may have to run it again and again, so I don't want to copy it to the remotes.

Comment: When you don't want to use all settings that `set` will show, you can try to change main.sh: Don't export the variables to the environment but echo them on the commandline like `var1=value1` and use `{ main.sh; cat ./sub.sh; } | ssh $user@$ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare -p` to pass variables :

```
{ declare -p dir1 dir2; cat ./sub.sh; } | ssh $user@$ip
```

Comment: Note that `declare -p` will print the variable declaration(s) in bash-compatible syntax; if the remote shell is different *and* any of the variables contain sufficiently weird characters, the declarations might get misparsed on the remote system. (Hopefully this will not be a problem.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson As OP tagged only `bash`, we would expect sub.sh is bash-compatible.

Comment: @Philippe I've learned not to trust the bash tag (or even people explicitly saying they're using bash) -- too many people seem to think it's a generic term for unix shells, or are confused about what they're actually using. I've even seen people identify DOS-style batch scripts as bash!

Answer (score 1):

You can store your variables in a .sh file like config.sh

When executing you can use following command `./sub.sh config.sh`

All the variables inside config.sh will be used as named variables (you can access them via name )
like `$dir1`

Comment: I don't see how this'd help with getting the variables substituted in the script on the remote computer.