# Can't build go program on remote server through remote ssh command

Tags: go, ssh

I'm trying to build go program on remote server from bash script but error (sh: 1: go: not found) returns. Same thing if I try to figure out the version:

```
ssh user@host "go version"
```

> sh: 1: go: not found

How to fix it? (`go` on that server exists and works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path to the `go` binary instead, don't rely on the `PATH`. Execute `whereis go` to check where it's located, so it should be sth like:

```
ssh user@host "/usr/local/go/bin/go version"
```

More information why did it happen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564729/997162) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man).