# What is the difference between interactive and non-interactive SSH commands?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, server

I am trying to execute a remote script on a server via SSH. Simple enough. I can do it through interactive SSH:

```
ssh username@host
pipenv install
```

And this works just fine. However, when I try to run the command all at once:

```
ssh username@host "pipenv install"
```

I get the following error:

```
pipenv: command not found
```

Why on earth might this be the case? My first thought was that I was getting dropped into a different shell (like sh), but running `ssh username@host 'echo $SHELL'` gives me the result of `/bin/bash`, which is exactly the same that I get via interactive ssh. What might be going on here? I was under the impression that interactive ssh was identical to non-interactive ssh.

Comment: One starts an interactive shell, one runs a noninteractive shell. Noninteractive shells don't run dotfiles (with the exception of any file named in the `ENV` environment variable in strictly POSIX-y shells, or `BASH_ENV` when bash is not running in POSIX compatibility mode).

Comment: Compare to `ssh -tt username@host <<<'pipenv install'`. Or, y'know, you can source your dotfiles (`.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, etc as-appropriate) explicitly.

Comment: I tried following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562722/command-not-found-via-ssh-with-single-command-found-after-connecting-to-termina) which seems to have identical issues, but no luck. I tried restarting the service after editing the file and rebooting the machine, neither fixed the issue.

Comment: `PermitUserEnvironment` is about the ssh client providing environment variables to the server, not about the server running dotfiles to set environment variables locally. Two different things, unrelated to each other.

Comment: `ssh -tt username@host <<< 'pipenv install' worked great!

Comment: So the underlying issue was that pipenv is added to PATH using a dotfile, and hence not being found, because this doesn't get sourced with a non-interactive shell?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: (using `ssh -tt` forces SSH to provide a TTY so it looks like an interactive session, and then `<<<'pipenv install'` is providing the command on stdin instead of the command line, _also_ making it look like an interactive session, so the shell runs in interactive mode and reads its dotfiles).