# perl: Run remote perl script through SSH and query environment variables on remote machine

Tags: perl, ssh, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

**Running on Mac OS X 10.8.2**

I'm running a perl script through SSH, in the perl script I query environment variables using 
$ENV{MY_VAR_NAME} and it works fine when run locally. But through SSH, all environment variables become unset.

I also tried to run

```
system("source ~/.bash_profile");
```

at the beginning of my script to no avail.

Any tips?

**EDIT:**

Rephrasing my question.

I have machine A and B. 
I ran my perl on machine B, trying to get the environment variables on B and it worked.
Then I ssh from A to B running the same script, i.e., using this code

```
ssh user@B perl myscript.pl
```

This time the environment variables on B are all blank.

Any tips?

**UPDATE:**

I found that running the above script, ~/.bashrc on Machine B was invoked, but after setting environment variables in ~/.bashrc, run the above command again and still I don't see any environment variables.

Also, if my perl script contains only

```
echo $ENV{PATH}
```

Then I get

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Not likely. A far more likely explanation is that you never set them in the first place.

Comment: `system("source ~/.bash_profile");` will launch a bourne shell, which is told told to run a bash script and exit. Any changes to that shell's environment is not going to affect the Perl process's environment.

Comment: Are you ssh'ing to a different machine and then running the program?  In that case no, it won't have your environment variables, those are specific to each machine (actually each shell which is why your `system` command didn't work).  Could you show what you mean by running Perl through ssh?

Comment: Can someone up-vote my question if you think my edited description makes sense?

Comment: @ikegami, I'm pretty sure that they are set since I ran the script on that machine and it sees them.

Comment: @Schwern thanks, that does look like it. I'll try and report back.

Comment: @kakyo, Let's put it this way: Perl does not unset environment variables. If they're not set, it's because they're not set in the parent process.

Comment: Can we not mark it as a duplicate? I have tried many solutions on the "Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?" None of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables which will get set when you use ssh to execute a command will depend on:

- the login shell
- the contents of the start up files for that shell

For example, when it start up `bash` may read any of the following files:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `/etc/profile`

depending on factors such as whether the shell is considered to be a "login" shell, is the session an "interactive" session, etc.

You should find out which start up files are being executed when you use `ssh`.

You can do this by just putting `echo here in XXXX` in the various files, and perform the ssh command. (Note that `ssh` with no command may invoke different start up files than `ssh` with a command.)

For `bash`, consult the section `INVOCATION` in its `man` page for a description of which files are read when `bash` starts up.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X (bash 4.1). I found that when running my perl script using ssh, the invoked scirpt was ~/.bashrc. But then if I put some env vars in that script. It still does not set it by the time the perl script runs.

Comment: Are those environment variables `export`-ed?

Comment: I came to realize that maybe this is a Mac OS X specific issue because none of these login-shell scripts worked in any ways of calling, either using "source XXX && perl myscript" in the ssh line or putting the "source" command at the top of my script. Also tested with shell script version instead of perl.

Comment: Put up a copy of the file `XXX` somewhere (i.e. pastbin.com)

Comment: To round out this answer add: see the ssh manpage on environment set by ssh. ~/.ssh/environment is run then ssh invokes bash. As already said if not interactive then bash will run different startup files.

Comment: Note that putting echo commands in startup files is fine but can cause unexpected trouble :-o. e.g. ssh port forward commands can silently fail if a startup script produces output.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to run `.bash_profile` and the perl script under the same remote shell session:

```
ssh user@B 'source ~/.bash_profile && perl myscript.pl'
```

Comment: Tried this and it still didn't work.

Comment: BTW, I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2.