# Are there differences between running ssh in interactive to non-interactive shell modes?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there a difference between doing ssh to get into a remote node and run commands there e.g. 
`ssh azg@zeus` then run commands as opposed to the scripting flavour `ssh azg@zeus 'command1 && command2 && command3 && etc'`?

I ask this because I see the applications don't behave exactly the same e.g. Akka works but produces some strange errors in the logs when I run the same server start using the scripting second choice. e.g. Will both flavours load `.bashrc` equally? Note I see the differences even if my first command is to `source .bashrc`

Comment: The latter will show up in your command history and may be a bad idea if passwords are involved in any of the commands

Comment: There are no passwords involved (I have setup private and public keys to be able to do that).

Comment: I did not mean the actual ssh command, which I expected to be a public/private key session; I was referring to the commands you pass to remote server e.g. if you try to do something to a remote (MySQL) database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its question has been closed as off-topic, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216204/3438854) covers it, I think.

If you need the added security that @vogomatix suggests (usually recommended), you'll need to establish the environment you want as part of the command, within the confines of the non-interactive shell.