# Source environment variables and execute bash before running local script on remote machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to execute the remote local script with ssh connection. I've read a document about the syntax of it. But my issue is that, before running the script, I need to execute bash and source environment variables.

This looks appropriate for me but it has not a source command :

```
ssh [user]@[server] 'bash -s' < [local_script]
```

I've tried such a thing with EOF but it didn't work for me too :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh  "$user@$$host" <<EOF
bash -s
source /dir/to/profile/.profile
source /dir/to/env/set/env.sh
/path/to/script/script.sh stop
EOF
```

Do you have an idea for this type of implementation of remote commands ? I have to source profile before the environment settings otherwise it gives an exception. But the main problem is about source.

Maybe it was an easy question but I don't have any ideas. Thank you in advance for your all answers.

Comment: Maybe `-t` option will help to initialize environment as in login shell. `ssh user@server 'bash -t -c local_script'`

Comment: The difference between your first example and your second is that the first example runs `bash -s` as the remote command and sends a script to it as input whereas the second example is sending four lines of text as standard input to the default command/shell on the remote host. If you move the `bash -s` to the command position in the second example does it work?

Comment: Two of these solutions won't work, I'v tried many things but it doesn't work!! :(

Comment: Do files like `/dir/to/profile/.profile` exist on the local machine or on the remote? - cause the way they are used now assumes they exist on the **remote**.

Comment: They exist on remote

Comment: "... trying to execute the remote local script... ". Wut? Is the script remote? Or local? It seems to me it can't be both...

Comment: @twalberg The script is local, but it's being run remotely (see the syntax in the question : `ssh [user]@[server] 'bash -s' < [local_script]`).  This functionality is built into SSH.  Also, for anyone finding this via a search engine, check out this question: [Source a script remotly via ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25870899/320399)

Comment: Another discussion I think it's worthy of linking to is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/216202/320399) one.  Specifically, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472444/320399) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by writing another template script that sources the environment variables and runs the script:

```
PROFILE=/dir/to/profile/.profile
source $PROFILE
cd /dir/to/script
/bin/bash script $1
```

If you use the `source` command with `bash` shell, `#!/bin/bash` doesn't work for the source command.

Answer (score 9):

**eval** can accomplish this for you:

```
eval $(cat /path/to/environment) ./script.sh
```

You can source multiple files this way too if you want if you know there
path:

```
eval $(cat /path/to/environment1 /path/to/environment2) ./script.sh
```

Or iterate over a directory:

```
eval $(cat $(find -type f /path/to/environments)) ./script.sh
```

Stick SSH in front of it if you're doing this remotely to solve your specific problem:

```
# note the quotes otherwise we'll source our local environment
ssh user@host "'eval $(cat /path/to/environment)' ./remote_script.sh"

# If it's a local environment you want to sort, then do the same
# command without the quotes:
ssh user@host "eval $(cat /path/to/environment)" ./remote_script.sh
```

If you want to source a remote environment into your own then use eval
locally as so:

```
eval "$(ssh user@host cat /path/to/environment)" ./local_script.sh
```

This alls you to source an external file setting it's environment variables in the same forked instance that will calls your script (making them available).

Consider a script file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$VAR1"
echo "$VAR2"
test_function
```

Now consider your environment file looks like this:

```
# Environment Variables
VAR1=foo
VAR2=bar
test_function()
{
   echo "hello world"
}
```

You'd see the output if you use the eval example:

```
foo
bar
hello world
```

Alternatively, if you just open up your script you wrote, you can source
these environment variables directly from within it and then you can just
call the script normally without any tricks:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Source our environment by starting with period an then following
# through with the full path to the environment file. You can also use
# the 'source' keyword here too instead of the period (.).
. /path/to/environment

echo "$VAR1"
echo "$VAR2"
test_function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old but just wanted to add that it can be done without an extra file - use '\' to escape local variables and remote command substitution - ie:

```
ssh me@somehost "RMTENV=\$(ls /etc/profile) && source \$RMTENV"
```

I use this to execute remote java commands and need the ENV to find java.