# Source a script remotly via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to run a remote program via ssh which requires a certain environment. Thus before executing the program I source a specific file building up the environment. If I'm logged onto the machine directly this is no problem but when I execute the command via ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=`ssh user@host "source ~/script.sh; ~/run/program"`
```

I get an error that indicates that the script was not sourced correctly. Do you know what I have to do in order to get the script sourced and the program executed in the same session?

EDIT: 
I'm exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the script and the executable is complaining that it cannot find the shared object file. The default shell is bash. 'Session' is definitive not the right wording. I meant 'terminal environment'.

Comment: "*I get an error that indicates that the script was not sourced correctly.*" You're going to need to be a lot more specific than that. Please update your question to show the *exact* error message (copy-and-paste it). I just tried a similar example, and it worked.

Comment: What was the error?  For example, if the user's shell on the remote machine is ksh, then `source` will not work, you have to use `.` instead.  If the sourced file does not export its variables, then the program will not see them regardless.  Also, what do you mean by "the same session"?  The program will run in a child process.

Comment: I edited the question above. @KeithThompson: Good to know that it must work in principle. I keep trying...

Comment: Are you *sure* that the "script.sh" set **all** the necessary variables to run that program?

Comment: You've *described* the error message. It would be more helpful to copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: The error when executing the program is simply `error while loading shared libraries: libCloudConnector.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` The sourcing itself generates no error.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you logged in directly, I assume it is as the identical user (`user`) and the command you typed in that case is, `source ~/script.sh; ~/run/program`, and that worked?

Comment: Can you run `ssh user@host 'source ~/script.sh; echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH'` and make sure the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is what you expect? (Be sure to use single quotes so the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is interpreted on the remote host).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the cleanest way, but if you invoke bash with the interactive option (-i) and send commands through the standard input, it should work.

In particular,

```
foo=`ssh user@host bash -i <<EOF
source ~/script.sh
~/run/program
EOF`
```

---

It would be much easier if you have a script `program_in_env.sh` that does exactly the two steps you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/script.sh
~/run/program
```

Then you would just need to call `ssh user@host program_in_env.sh`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your time and help. I found the issue. The basic idea of how to execute the remote program was right from the beginning. When testing my case locally on the machine, the current working directory was different. For some reason the cwd is important when sourcing this bash script.