# 'make' through ssh not compiling

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, makefile

im trying to execute a `make` command through ssh and still cannot know the reasons why its not working:

I have done so far:

Sending cmd directly on ssh

```
ssh root@server 'cd /path/;make foo'
make: *** No rule to make target `foo'.  Stop.
```

After ssh login

```
ssh root@server
root@server# cd /path/
root@server# make foo
ok
```

testing

```
ssh root@server 'echo blah;echo bleh'
blah
bleh
```

Comment: Are we supposed to diagnose it solely based on "it's not working"?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run make through ssh? Where is the makefile? Is it in root's home directory?

Comment: Is `make` the only program that doesn't work? What if you do `ssh root@server echo foo`?

Comment: OK, i have looked so far where the problem might be:

ssh root@server 'make foo'
make: *** No rule to make target `foo'.  Stop.

ssh root@server
#make foo
OK.

ssh root@server 'echo blah'
blah

Comment: What does the makefile look like? (I assume `ok` is not literally the entire output from running `make foo`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after nearly a day fighting I found out:

[Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

Thank you all.