# Capistrano passenger-config restart-app command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, passenger, capistrano3

I have run into an issue restarting my Rails application during the deployment process using Capistrano. Here is a trace of the problem code:

```
INFO [e14478ef] Running /usr/bin/env rvmsudo passenger-config restart-app /var/www/appname/staging/ --ignore-app-not-running as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
DEBUG [e14478ef] Command: rvmsudo passenger-config restart-app
DEBUG [e14478ef]        bash: rvmsudo: command not found
```

I am almost certain this issue is stemming from the environment from which the command is being executed ($BASH_ENV), but I'm not sure how to remedy the issue. When I execute the same command manually from the command line, everything works fine. My app is using:

- Ruby (2.2.0)
- Rails (4.2.0)
- Capistrano (3.4.0)
- Capistrano-passenger (0.0.4)
- Capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
- Capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
- Passenger (5.0.6)

**Just a note:** I have been able to restart the app by overwriting the passenger:restart task and using the old touch tmp/restart.txt method. However, I would really like to know how to get the default restart method working correctly.

**Update:** I was able to circumvent the problem by replacing the default restart task with the following code:

```
desc 'Restart your Passenger application - temporary fix'  
task :restart do  
  on roles(:app) do  
    sudo "passenger-config restart-app #{fetch(:deploy_to)}"  
  end  
end
```

I am still interested in learning how to restart the app without overwriting the default task, but I have added the code above for those who may be stuck in a similar situation.

(Credit: https://github.com/capistrano/passenger/issues/9#issuecomment-92685064)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a command not found for `rvmsudo`, it is probably because you [don't have rvmsudo installed](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo).

Comment: rvmsudo is installed. I think the issue involves the "shell" from which the command is executed, which I believe is non-interactive, so it doesn't have the necessary permissions to execute many commands. The top answer to this thread gives a good overview of the different shell environments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man