# How can I make pycharm remote execution use the system environment variables?

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-execution

I'm using pycharm remote execution to run scripts on a remote server.
I saw that bash_profile (or other start up scripts) aren't executed - is there a way to make this happen?

preferably not in 'run configurations' which are needed for each script (I have many scripts) but in a shared configuration

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm very surprised that your question hasn't been answered or commented on at all for nearly 7 months. Is this problem really that uncommon?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't actually related with Pycharm.

You must add your environment variable to remote machine ~/.bashrc

```
VAR="VALUE"
export VAR
```

You can read the from
[Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

if you use Vagrant you can use this too