# How do I set Linux environment variables so that pm2 can see them for node.js apps?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, pm2

When I run my nodejs application on my Ubuntu Linux server using `node server.js` it works correctly, and outputs the value of the environment variable `$db` using **process.env.db**.

However, the app breaks when running `sudo pm2 start server.js`, seeing the environment variable as **undefined**.

I've tried adding the variable in the following files:

- etc/environment: `db="hello"`
- ~/.ssh/environment : `db="hello"`
- ~/.bashrc : `export db="hello"`

I've also rebooted and run `source ~/.bashrc` to ensure the variable is available.

I think I've tried everything mentioned here, I don't know what else to do:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables
- https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/867
- [Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/389601/etc-environment-export-path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that saying `source ~/.bashrc` you are loading the variables on your current user. However, when you say `sudo ...` you are running with the user `root`, so this won't change.

What you can do is to use `sudo` with `-E`:

```
sudo -E pm2 start server.js
```

From `man sudo`:

```
-E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to reserve their
             existing environment variables.  The security policy may eturn an error
             if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I don't understand why, surely having the variable in etc/environment means that the root user can see it? I thought the problem was the opposite - that my user couldn't see it and therefore I had to add the variable to the ~/ files as well as etc/environment.

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact you are saying `db="hello"` in `/etc/environment`. If you do not define it with `export`, the variable is not available to the sub-processes. Saying `export db="hello"` in that file should make it.

Comment: I don't think so, from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables - "It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line." But anyway, it doesn't matter, I know how to get it to work now, thanks.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is loaded during login/authentication. Isn't set automatically when is modified.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this thread https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/204

Seems like your environment variables get's cached.

Comment: As suggested I tried running **sudo pm2 kill** to shutdown the whole process and then restarted it, to get the new variable, but it still doesn't work. I've rebooted the machine too so I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question "how do I set environment variables so that PM2 can see them for node.js". It's also link-only. It should be deleted or converted to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the pm2 process and started it again as normal. simply restarting the process didn't work though.

Answer (score -1):

So according to Vlad Miller note, need to restart pm2 process with  **--update-env** argument

Comment: This should perhaps be an edit on Vlad's answer rather an answer of its own.