# how to reload etc/environment variables

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I added some variables in `etc/environment`:

```
MY_API_KEY="123123123"
MY_API_SECRET="also123123"
```

I tried using:

```
sudo reboot
pm2 restart server
```

but in my application the `process.env` does not log out the new variables added. I'm running on `ubuntu 16.04.3` with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variables. 
Then `pm2 save` 
and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Restart pm2 process with **--update-env** argument.
Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897979/2090822 , https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/204#issuecomment-334171568