# Executable not found after setting environmental variables in Ansible Playbook

Tags: java, ansible, environment-variables

I need to deploy a bunch of machines from Ansible, these machines need to execute a suite of programs that run on the JVM and one hard requisite is that **I need to deploy the JDK** **from a tar.gz** without leveraging RedHat's repositories.

So I need to define an environment variable to the JDK's folder on my hosts and I tried to achieve this with these tasks:

```
- name: Set JDK environment variables
  become: yes
  lineinfile: 
    path: /etc/profile
    state: present
    line:"{{item}}"
  with_items:
    - 'export JAVA_HOME="{{java_dir}}"'
    - 'export PATH=$PATH;$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'

- name: Reload environment variables
  shell:
    cmd: source /etc/profile
```

At this point the variables seem to be correctly set on the system, because if I login into any of the machines the `java --version` command works.

Now when the playbook tries to execute a task that needs to be run from the JVM I get this error:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "./kafka-storage.sh",
        "random-uuid"
    ],
    .....
    .....
    .....
}

STDERR:

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh line 346: exec : java: not found

MSG:

non-zero return code
```

Please keep in mind this playbook used to install the JDK from the internal repositories and everything worked flawlessly so this can't be the fault of Kafka's executable.

I tried to make sure that they can be seen from Ansible I also perform this task that adds this path to the user's home that Ansible is operating with:

```
- name: Set JDK environment for next tasks
  become: yes
  lineinfile: 
    path: /home/user/.bashrc
    state: present
    line:"{{item}}"
  with_items:
    - 'export JAVA_HOME="{{java_dir}}"'
    - 'export PATH=$PATH;$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

But still the Kafka executable can't find Java's folder.

Comment: I believe, you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988567/ansible-doesnt-load-profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually solved this by writing the env variables in a .bash_profile file on the host machine.

```
- name: Set environmental variables
  become: yes
  blockinfile:
    path: "/[path]/.bash_profile"
    state: present
    block: |
      export JAVA_HOME="{{path_to_jdk}}"
      export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And then used the env vars for a specific task that I needed to run:

```
- name: Perform task
  shell: source /[path]/.bash_profile && command.sh
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    become: true
```

This probably doesn't permanently set these env variables for the rest of the playbook's tasks but it might be viable for one or two tasks.