# ssh command fail but work on server Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables, fabric

I'm trying to retrieve the PHP version on the remote server with fabric, but when I execute my command in fabric it returns me : /bin/bash: php: command not found.

When I connect via ssh on the server then try `php -v` it returns me the php version. but when I try `ssh user@host 'php -v'` I have the same error than fabric ( /bin/bash: php: command not found)

I think my problem comes from the environment variable right?  Is there a way to load the proper env variable so my command doesn't fail in fabric?

Comment: is there a difference between `ssh user@host env` and running `env` in an interactive shell?

Comment: Have you tried to call php with its absolute path?

Comment: @SimonFraser yes, `ssh user@host env` has less value than just in `env`  after loggin with ssh
@zezollo I tried to find the absolute path but i didn't succeed. shouldn't it be /bin/bash/php ?

Comment: It depends on your OS. Though I wouldn't expect it to be `/bin/bash/php`. When you're connected to your server, you should be able to use `whereis php` to find its absolute path. (`whereis` is installed on FreeBSD and on Ubuntu linux at least).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man though