# Jenkins slave node is offline: Authentication failed

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have a node that is using user/password ssh authentication. The node is being reported as offline, and when I try to launch the agent i get:

```
[02/23/17 15:32:00] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to myUrl:22.
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as myUser. Wrong password. (credentialId:lawrence/method:keyboard-interactive)
[02/23/17 15:32:02] [SSH] Authentication failed.
hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1217)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:711)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:706)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[02/23/17 15:32:02] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/23/17 15:32:02] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I have confirmed that the username and password are correct as I managed to login with them manually myself.

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that jenkins user cannot read SSH private key.
You should enter private key directly.
[image]

Comment: you're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging in, try doing a

```
ssh slave command
```

I am suspecting your login profiles are the culprit. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)