# Differing PHP versions using ssh

Tags: php, ssh, remote-server, bash, php-deployer

I am trying to setup deployer php on a shared server. And having trouble running php remotely on the server.

The server is running php 7.0.6 for normal http requests. And if I SSH in via terminal and run `php -v` on the remote server I get:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: May  2 2016 02:11:49) ( NTS )
```

this seems good to go but if I run a remote command from my local machine:

```
$ ssh  'user@domain.com' 'php -v'
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Mar 29 2014 12:18:37)
```

obviously the remote command is not using the right php version. I found the version is set in the `.bash_porfile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/crucial-php/php-7.0.600/bin:$PATH
```

but I don't know how to get the ssh remote command to respect the `.bash_profile`. Is there anyway to get the remote command to use the modified PATH without forcing it with `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Run `which php` instead to shed some light into the situation. Most likely there's a different user used for the two sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be pretty simple, after reading this post:

[Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

I copied the `PATH` var into my `~/.bashrc` file and it worked like a charm.