# sqlplus through SSH failed to resolve tns

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, sqlplus, amazon-rds, tnsping

I setup an EC2 instance and RDS instance. Then installed oracle instance client on EC2 instance. After that I managed to do sqlplus and connect with database from EC2 instance. To do that I created a tnsnames.ora file and enter the service details of the database.

I can do,

```
sqlplus user/password@db_alias
```

But I cannot do, (This gives ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified)

```
ssh username@ip sqlplus user/password@db_alias
```

Password less ssh also configured. And I'm doing the ssh to the current machine itself. Any thought would be helpful.

Addition to the details. Since I installed oracle instance client, tnsping command is not available. I achieve this by adding following function to the .profile file.

```
whence tnsping >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
  tnsping() {
    sqlplus -L -s x/x@$1 </dev/null |
      grep ORA- |
        (grep -v ORA-01017 || echo OK)
  }
```

Comment: Where did you create `tnsnames.ora`? Your environment may be missing a `$TNS_ADMIN` variable pointing to its location when you ssh in like that, though it seems to have the `$PATH` and other Oracle variables already.

Comment: @AlexPoole I put the tnsnames.ora in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. Also set the $TNS_ADMIN to above mentioned path. Some times it may be a permission issue of the tnsnames.ora. I'll check.

Comment: But how are you setting `TNS_ADMIN` - manually in your shell before you call `ssh`? Or in an environment file (.bashrc, .prifle etc.) so it is picked up by the new session that `sqlplus` is being run in?

Comment: I added it to the Environment file. So I hope it is available for each session. Addition to the previous comment. tnsnames.ora file has the required permission level.

Comment: @AlexPooleYup! The variable is not available at the time of doing sqlplus via ssh. My OS is ubuntu. So the `.profile` has an entry to source `.bashrc` and `.bashrc` has those records. I cannot think a reason for not setting the environment variables.

Comment: I found the reason for `bashrc` is not been loaded. In `bashrc` there is a validation to check the login shell is interactive or non-interactive. If not running interactively, `bashrc` exit. So I defined the variables at the beginning of the file. Thanks @AlexPoole for your thought.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be able to narrow down to the problem in loading environment variables (specifically `$TNS_ADMIN`). Since the `.bashrc` has an validation to check the login shell is an interactive one or non-interactive one, the variables which defined at the bottom was not loaded.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

The reason for tns not to be resolved via ssh is unavailability of `$TNS_ADMIN` variable. By defining that variables at the beginning of `.bashrc`, I could able to fix this.

See Also [Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)