# Script invoked from remote server unable to run service correctly

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a unix script  that invokes another script on a remote unix server.

amongst other commands i am stopping a service. The stop command essentially translates to

```
ssh -t -t -q ${AEM_USER}@${SERVERIP}   'bash -l -c "service aem stop"'
```

The service is getting stopped but when i start back the service it just creates the .pid file and does not perform the start up. When i run the command for start i.e.

```
ssh -t -t -q ${AEM_USER}@${SERVERIP}   'bash -l -c "service aem start"'
```

it does not show any error. On going to the server and checking the status

```
service aemauthor status
```

Below message is displayed

```
aem dead but pid file exists
```

Also when starting the service by logging in to the server, it works as expected along with the message

```
Removing stale pidfile (pid: 8701)
Starting aem
```

Comment: Why do you execute another shell, why not `ssh <options> user@server "my_command <argument>" `. `service stop` not deleting the `<pid>` file could be due to how the `service` is designed.

Comment: The service stop is just one of the thing it does. The script performs a bunch of other things. also the service works perfectly when i run it on the same server

Comment: Well, what do you want us to do?  You already diagnosed the problem.  Something causes the service script to not remove the pid file, and understandably this raises problems when trying to restart the service.  Find out why the pid file isn't removed properly upon `stop` and remove the reason, or remove the pid yourself.

Comment: @user1643087 When you manually run the script do you run it as a `sudo user` or the `user` you have mentioned in the question. Also, can you share your `maintenance.sh` script? Also, try running your script in debug mode, i.e `-x`.

Comment: Can you tell what service is it?
Can you check what owner and permission have the .pid file? (ls -l /path/pidfile.pid) Are you sure that the user has enough permissions in order to delete the .pid file?

Comment: Updated the question to make it easier to replicate

Comment: Consider removing the `-q` from ssh to see if it sheds a light on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know the details of the service script of aem.

I guess the problem is related to the [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) signal. When we log off from a shell or disconnect from ssh, the OS will send `HUP` signal to all processes that started in this terminated shell. If the process didn't handle the `HUP` signal, it would exit by default.

When we run a command via ssh remotely, the process started by this command will receive `HUP` signal after ssh session is terminated.

We can use the [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command to ignore the `HUP` signal.

You can try

```
ssh -t -t -q ${AEM_USER}@${SERVERIP} 'bash -l -c "nohup service aem start"'
```

If it works, you can use `nohup` command to start aem in the service script.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at [the stale pidfile syndrome](http://perfec.to/stalepid.html), there are different reasons for pidfiles getting stalled, like for instance some issues with the way your handles its removal when the process exits... but considering your only experiencing when running remotely, I would guess it might be related to what is being loaded or not by your profile... check the most voted solid answer at the post below for some insights:

- [Why Does SSH Remote Command Get Fewer Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

As described in the comments of the mentioned post, you can try sourcing `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile` before executing your script to test it, or even trying to execute `env` locally and remotelly to compare variables that are being sourced or not.