# SSH Remote get fewer environment variables on Oracle Linux 7

Tags: c#, linux, oracle, ssh, environment-variables

I am traying to access **Oracle Linux Server 7** via **SSH** and connecting successfully.
Whenever want to get all enviroment variables via **powershell** its work fine , but i am getting fewer enviroment variables when i use [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) (.NET SSH Library)

**Here is my code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = $"host";
    var user = "username";
    var pwd = "password";
 
    ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, 22, user,
        new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            // Pasword based Authentication
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user,pwd),
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("rsa.key"),

        }
    );
    using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
    {
        sshclient.Connect();
        if (sshclient.IsConnected)
        {
            RunCommand(sshclient, "printenv");
            sshclient.Disconnect();
        }

    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I was tried some solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man) but i didn't get any result.So what can i do in this situation?

Comment: The most likely explanation is connecting via powershell is creating an interactive session (you don't show the command you ran so this is an educated guess) while your .NET program is creating a non-interactive session. If you do `ssh $host printenv` from powershell do you see the same set of env vars you see when running your .NET program? If yes then that's the reason.

Comment: @KurtisRader i know reason caused by that but how can i solve this ?

Comment: Your original question makes it quite clear you did not know the reason for the difference in behavior. You "solve this" by either configuring your .NET program to establish an interactive SSH session, or you reconfigure the remote shell to set the desired env vars for non-interactive shells, or you configure SSH to pass the desired env vars from the client to server machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ssh login don't load the user profile.

I get the complete Environment Variables of `printenv` by executing the profile first.

```cs
//RunCommand(sshclient, "printenv");
var result = sshclient.RunCommand(". .bash_profile && printenv");
 Console.WriteLine((result.Result));
```